# How can I add a new attribute from another table to a serializer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have the following tables:

```
Table1
    :name
    :resource

Table2
    :FK Table1
    :FK Other Table
    :quantity
```

And the following serializer

```
class Table1 < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id,
             :name,
             :resource
end
```

What I need is that the serializer returns all its attributes and the `quantity` from `Table2`, where it has a relationship.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActiveModel::Serializer` actually supports this, here is my example

```
class Table1Serializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :resource
  has_one :table_2, serializer: Table2Serializer
end

class Table2Serializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :quantity
end
```

So you just specify the relation with the corresponding serializer it will work, btw I use `Table1Serializer` instead of `Table1` to avoid misunderstanding with `Table1` (model)

Another option is, if you don't want to write the `Table2Serializer`, you can use custom attribute, it is like:

```
class Table1Serializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
   attributes :id, :name, :resource
   attributes :table_2

   def table_2
     object.table_2
   end
end
```

So 2 ways you can apply, but for relation like you mentioned, I prefer the first option, because I may use `Table2Serializer` later!

Comment: I'm using the custom attribute, but when I try `object.table_2.attributes.slice('id', 'quantity')` it says that `attributes` is an `undefined method`. If I only use `object.table_2` it shows me all the data.

Comment: Hmmm, is object.table_2 a active record, btw if you want show all attributes of table_2, just use object.table_2, check my update!